# How to make JAWS (the screen reader) read 2 different controls one by one

Tags: c#, wpf, jaws-screen-reader

I have a WPF dialog with 2 controls on it. Currently JAWS can only read one of them which got the focus on.

The target is to make JAWS read both of them.
-   Is it possible to programmingly move the focus from one control to another?
-   Or any other suggestions to implement this function.

Answer (score 0):

Can you press tab key and check whether the second control gets focus and reads.